# glXChooseFBConfig returns NULL

Tags: opengl, glew, mesa, glx

I'm trying to configure a framebuffer on a computer which has no dedicated graphics card. Only mesa GL.

I've tried multiple FB configurations but I can't seem to get a non-NULL return. The same code works on another computer with nvidia drivers..

```
OpenGL vendor string: Tungsten Graphics Inc
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Desktop
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 8.0.4
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
```

The mesa examples that works on another computer also fails at the same glXFBConfig line.

Here's the relevant part of the code

```
int fbAttribs[] = {
       None
    };

  int numberOfFramebufferConfigurations = 0;
  GLXFBConfig* fbConfigs = glXChooseFBConfig(self->display, DefaultScreen(self->display), fbAttribs, &numberOfFramebufferConfigurations);
```

As I said, I tried with different configurations such as:

```
   int fbAttribs[NUM_FB_CONFIGS][100] = {
      {
         /* Single buffered, with depth buffer */
         GLX_RENDER_TYPE, GLX_RGBA_BIT,
         GLX_DRAWABLE_TYPE, GLX_PBUFFER_BIT,
         GLX_RED_SIZE, 1,
         GLX_GREEN_SIZE, 1,
         GLX_BLUE_SIZE, 1,
         GLX_DEPTH_SIZE, 1,
         GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER, 0,
         GLX_STENCIL_SIZE, 0,
         None
      },
      {
         /* Double buffered, with depth buffer */
         GLX_RENDER_TYPE, GLX_RGBA_BIT,
         GLX_DRAWABLE_TYPE, GLX_PBUFFER_BIT,
         GLX_RED_SIZE, 1,
         GLX_GREEN_SIZE, 1,
         GLX_BLUE_SIZE, 1,
         GLX_DEPTH_SIZE, 1,
         GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1,
         GLX_STENCIL_SIZE, 0,
         None
      },
      {
         /* Single buffered, without depth buffer */
         GLX_RENDER_TYPE, GLX_RGBA_BIT,
         GLX_DRAWABLE_TYPE, GLX_PBUFFER_BIT,
         GLX_RED_SIZE, 1,
         GLX_GREEN_SIZE, 1,
         GLX_BLUE_SIZE, 1,
         GLX_DEPTH_SIZE, 0,
         GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER, 0,
         GLX_STENCIL_SIZE, 0,
         None
      },
      {
         /* Double buffered, without depth buffer */
         GLX_RENDER_TYPE, GLX_RGBA_BIT,
         GLX_DRAWABLE_TYPE, GLX_PBUFFER_BIT,
               GLX_RENDER_TYPE, GLX_RGBA_BIT,
         GLX_DRAWABLE_TYPE, GLX_PBUFFER_BIT,
         GLX_RED_SIZE, 1,
         GLX_GREEN_SIZE, 1,
         GLX_BLUE_SIZE, 1,
         GLX_DEPTH_SIZE, 0,
         GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1,
         GLX_STENCIL_SIZE, 0,
         None
      }
   };
  GLX_RED_SIZE, 1,
         GLX_GREEN_SIZE, 1,
         GLX_BLUE_SIZE, 1,
         GLX_DEPTH_SIZE, 0,
         GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1,
         GLX_STENCIL_SIZE, 0,
         None
      }
   };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question with the solution.

This actually ended up being the OpenGL context not supporting the required extensions.
In this case, I was ssh'ing (with -X) into the machine and running the binary that does all the OpenGL computation. In such cases the hosts or the client's OpenGL may be used  depending on the $DISPLAY variable. Setting the DISPLAY variable to :0.0 meant use the host's OpenGL, which solved the problems.

Comment: I have set the `DISPLAY` variable to `:0` with `export DISPLAY=:0`. It  was previously set to `:1`. I am also ssh'ing into the machine, although I did not provide the `-X` option. Should I? In any case, `glXChooseFBConfig` still fails.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check, that `GLX` is actually available? Also for glXChooseFBConfig to work the server must support the `Render` extension. Both `GLX` and `Render` are widely supported these days. But they may not, so you have to check. Use `glXQueryExtension` to check for GLX and `XRenderQueryExtension` to check for `Render`.